# How would I select the last of each user's record from a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have table of financial transactions, each one includes a `balance` column that's essentially the result of all the previous line items.

What I want to get is the most recent transaction for each user (`manager`, in this case) so I can get their current `balance`.

```
id  manager_id  balance
1   1           500
2   2           300
3   1           200
4   1           175
5   2           200
```

So in this case I'd want to get back that manager_id 2 has a balance of 200 and manager_id 1 has a balance of 175.

Something in the vein of `Financial.order('id DESC').uniq(:manager_id)` (though that doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If well this may not be the most efficient but assuming you don't have 100s of managers, you could just do:

```
id  manager_id  balance
1   1           500
2   2           300
3   1           200
4   1           175
5   2           200


mids = Financial.all.pluck(:manager_id).uniq
mids.map{|mid| Financial.where(manager_id: mid).last}
```

Update, this seems too simple but based on your data example I was able to do:

```
Financial.group(:manager_id).pluck(:manager_id, :balance)
# => [[1, 175], [2, 200]]
```

Or if you prefer array of hash data returned:

```
Financial.group(:manager_id).pluck(:manager_id, :balance).map{|a| {manager_id: a[0], balance: a[1]}}
# =>[{:manager_id=>1, :balance=>175}, {:manager_id=>2, :balance=>200}]
#
```

Haven't tested on larger data set, but I suspect it will work.

Comment: Eh, I have 10's of thousands of Managers. 

Comment: so you need to return an activerecord relation with the data? or do you want ruby objects?

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to do is get manager records (from an associated table) and show their most recent balance. Presumably the AR relation with the data is what would be most useful.

Comment: I updated my answer, it seems to give the result you're looking for.